# celery with redis broker visibility timeout

Tags: python, redis, celery

I'm trying to achieve the following behaviour:

1. start celery task using celery beat
2. worker is killed
3. a new worker initiated
4. the task started over again

for doing so i set `acks_late=True` flag, and `'visibility_timeout': 30`

meaning if the task did not ack in 30 seconds, a new one should be added to the queue

from some reason this does not happen

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be with gevent

when i `monkey.patch_all()` the retry mechanism will not work